# Chrome Developer tools missing timeline views/modules

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

So under timeline I would normal see options such as Events, Frames, Memory in the upper left but I no longer do. I'm not sure what I did but what I have there now is two checkboxes: capture stacks and capture memory. How can I get back the original setup?

Comment: Have a version number?  Tried a difference machine?  I don't see those options either, but I'm a dev tools novice.  Google probably decided you no longer need them.

Comment: version: 36.0.1985.125.   What do you see in the upper left quadrant?

Comment: Your right.  The new version changes this